# XSLT: omit declaration embedded within text

Tags: python, xslt, groovy, declaration, xalan

Hope you guys can help. I have a string (bear in mind it is XML-like but my application treats it as a binary string) that contains multiple xml declarations within the text. I would like to remove these declarations. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Child1>
    .
    .
    </Child1>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Child2>
    .
    .
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

omit-xml-declaration="yes" will not work in this case as it cannot get to the declarations within the document. Is there any way I can escape any declarations other than the first one using XSLT? I could perhaps CDATA these somehow (not sure this would work though)

Comment: Ok this breaks because it is not well formed XML. Sadly the application that generates the messages essentially merges two docs into one. Any way at all I could get rid of the extra declarations, perhaps Python?

Comment: `omit-xml-declaration` is used to control the _output_ of the XSLT processor, it doesn't affect the input.  As you have rightly stated, `<?xml` anywhere other than the very beginning of the file is not well-formed XML.

Comment: is this XML like a live feed or is it a file that is physically stored?

Comment: As the OP already stated, this is not valid XML. As a consequence, you cannot use XSLT alone to solve this problem. Perhaps you could use regex to remove all the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` substrings?

Comment: This XML is from a live feed so I can't really run a script on a file on disk. I am looking at Groovy to see if I can somehow get it to delete the declarations based on a pattern. I have never worked with Groovy so it is a hit-and-miss exercise at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve with XSLT!

Reason: The parser requires valid XML. And the sample code that you have listed isn't a valid XML.

Solution:

1. If it is possible to modify the source code that is producing such kind of XMLs, then correct it! Since the second suggestion is not recommended! or else if you don't have a choice then
2. Modify XML by replacing this declaration part with null/whitespace using either host programs like C# or Java using string manupulation OR Using regular Expressions.  RegEx would be more useful since the string pattern is always common through out the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree it is not valid XML and therefore XSLT will not be able to remove the declaration. Only option (given the application constraints I have) is to use Groovy/Python to parse the 'text' and remove the XML declarations (that occur anywhere in the file). Anyone have sample(s) that I could use as reference? I have never done scripting of that sort but I am sure can work something out based on examples.

Comment: Well. I wish if I could help you but I am not aware of Python neither Groovy! If it's regEx then yah should be an easy shot!